# Automapper Expression mapping one property to many

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm running a WebAPI,

> ```
> Asp.Net Core 3.1
> Automapper: 9.0
> Automapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping: 3.1
> ```

My LocaleDto PK is a composite key of 2 FK - `LanguageCode` and `CountryCode`

```
  public class LocaleDto 
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(Language)), Column(Order = 0)]
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }

        public LanguageDto Language { get; set; }

        [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(Country)), Column(Order = 1)]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        public CountryDto Country { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to map LocaleDto to LocaleViewModel, where `Id` is build based on the following pattern `languageCode-CountryCode` ie. `en-GB`

```
 public class LocaleViewModel 
    {
        public string Id {get;set;}
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public LanguageViewModel Language { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public CountryViewModel Country { get; set; }
    }
```

The following mapping works just fine when I map one object to another using a static helper method:

```
  CreateMap<LocaleDto, LocaleViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => LocalisationHelper.ToLocaleCode(src.LanguageCode, src.CountryCode)));

            CreateMap<LocaleViewModel, LocaleDto>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.LanguageCode, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.LanguageCode))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryCode, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.CountryCode));
...
  public static string ToLocaleCode(string languageCode, string countryCode)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(languageCode) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryCode))
            {
                return $"{languageCode}-{countryCode}";
            }
            return null;
        }
```

But when I map the expression, the result is not understandable in LINQ to SQL, cause it contains the helper LocalisationHelper.ToLocaleCode.

```
Expression<Func<LocaleViewModel, bool>> filter = x => x.Id == "en-GB";
var entityFilter = mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<LocaleDto, bool>>>(filter);
```

**Inspect of entityFilter:**

```
 {Param_0 => (ToLocaleCode(Param_0.LanguageCode, Param_0.CountryCode) == "en-GB")}
```

**Exception**

```
     The LINQ expression 'DbSet<LocaleDto>
         .Where(l => LocalisationHelper.ToLocaleCode(
             languageCode: l.LanguageCode, 
             countryCode: l.CountryCode) == "en-GB")' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
     or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
     either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
     ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
     more information.
```

**Is there a way to differently map those properties in Automapper so the result can be translated to SQL, without the need of switching to client evaluation?**

Comment: Try writing it in LINQ first, without AM. An then you'll be able to bring AM back in. Also search previous solutions, people did this before.

Comment: it works just fine with linq to Dto directly

Comment: Really? :) How would that call `ToLocaleCode`? Clearly that's another code.

Comment: Im quite confused with the comments you have provided. Did you read this question and understand it fully ? ToLocaleCode is a helper for the mapping. It causes the actual issue. What's the value of trying anything "without automapper first" if the mapping is the one and only thing I'm trying to fix..

Answer (score 1):

What if you tried instead of using a static function evaluate the expression directly

```
CreateMap<LocaleDto, LocaleViewModel>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LanguageCode + "-" + src.CountryCode));
```

Comment: I would have to check if adding strings make any difference, but I tested string interpolation $"{lolaleCode}-{countryCode}" without the helper (in the mapping directly) and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` condition in your current linq is generated `on the server`, and your server does not define the LocalisationHelper.ToLocaleCode method, so this exception will occur.

To solve this problem, you only need to `convert the DbSet<LocaleDto> to list or enumerable` before the where condition(which has mentioned in the exception), so that the where condition can be guaranteed to run under `the client condition`.

Change your code as follow:

```
DbSet<LocaleDto>.ToList().Where(l => LocalisationHelper.ToLocaleCode(l.LanguageCode,l.CountryCode) == "en-GB")
```

## Update

Here is the second method:

```
Func<LocaleDto, bool> IsMatch = (x) =>
            ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.LanguageCode) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.CountryCode))
            ? $"{x.LanguageCode}-{x.CountryCode}" : null) == "en-GB";

var query = DbSet<LocaleDto>.Where(IsMatch).ToList();
```

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59760973/12884742) .

Comment: That would work, but that's client evaluation, so something I want to avoid doing.  It's not an issue for locale that has 10 or so rows, but I have the same problem with translation dto (hundreds or thousands of entries). Its not an acceptable solution to fetch them all from db and filter out in memory

Comment: @Konrad,I have updated my post, there is another way you can try.