# calling a method from a linq query throws "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed..."

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Given this sample pseudo code:

```
var student = from s in ctx.Students
              where s.StudentName == "Bill"
              let code = GetCode(s.Id)
              select new
              {
                 Name = s.StudentName,
                 Code = code.Code
              };

private Code GetCode(int id)
{
     return ctx.Codes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

I get this error message:

> "A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using
>   the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not
>   guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested
>   query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the
>   query avoiding nested invocations."

But if I explicitely write the query within the let clause it works ok:

```
var student = from s in ctx.Students
              where s.StudentName == "Bill"
              let ctx.Codes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == s.Id)
              select new
              {
                 Name = s.StudentName,
                 Code = code.Code
              };
```

Is there a way I can call the GetCode method without getting any error?

Comment: It's more efficient to throw away `GetCode` and use `join`.

Comment: Change the method signature: `Code GetCode(YourContext ctx, int id)`.

Comment: @Dennis this is a sample code - my query is much more complex

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I tried that and I got the same error

Comment: @user441365: how query complexity stops you from using joins? Your second sample works, but it leads to sub-query. From the database point this is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using EF. My assumtion/explanation would be next: your `IQueryable` which you are creating via LINQ is compiled via [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) into SQL. EF does not know how to convert you `GetCode` into SQL and it is handled as lets call it `last` statement in your query, so it can just evaluates it and tries to make query to the DB, and it sees that's there is an operation already started on your context(which is generating the first SQL). But in second case it can translate your query fully to SQL and make one call to the db.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - is there any way around this so I can call a function?

Comment: @user441365 can't find an elegant solution from top of my head, but you can try to implement a nasty one like [this](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/custom-functions-using-imethodcalltranslator-in-2-1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem related to [`client evaluation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval). The condition behind where is running on the server, and the server side does not define the `GetCode` method, so the server side cannot recognize the GetCode method and cause an error.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392778/automapper-expression-mapping-one-property-to-many).

The solution is to execute the entire SQL statement `on the client` and convert `ctx.Students` into a collection form `ctx.Students.ToList()`.

```
var student = from s in ctx.Students.ToList()
              where s.StudentName == "Bill"
              let code = GetCode(s.Id)
              select new
              {
                 Name = s.StudentName,
                 Code = code.Code
              };
```