# Linq Where Clause 'AND' 'OR'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

just wanna know how to use Linq if i have this code.

```
private IQueryable<viewTable> BaseQuery(Models.TestDataContext db)
{
   IQueryable<viewTable> query = db.viewTables;

   foreach (string row in gridCompany.GridView.GetSelectedFieldValues("CompanyCode"))
        query = query.Where(t => t.Comp_Code == row.ToString());

   return query;
}
```

This code return query

```
SELECT [t0].[Column]
FROM [dbo].[viewTable] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[CompanyCode] = 'ALPHA') **AND** ([t0].[CompanyCode] = 'BETA')
ORDER BY [t0].[EditDate] DESC
```

How to achieve query result to

```
SELECT [t0].[Column]
FROM [dbo].[viewTable] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[CompanyCode] = 'ALPHA') **OR** ([t0].[CompanyCode] = 'BETA')
ORDER BY [t0].[EditDate] DESC
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should rather build predicate in loop and then apply it at once ... just replace `AndAlso` with `OrElse` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630723/add-two-expressions-to-create-a-predicate-in-entity-framework-core-3-does-not-wo

Comment: Appending `Where` clauses will indeed result in an `AND` operation in sql. I think one way you could deal with is, is creating an array or list from the value's of your gridview and then use `Contains` inside you `Where`. Also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439142/c-sharp-linq-statements-with-or-clauses) very simular question

Comment: fx something like https://dotnetfiddle.net/1VpAe4 and as [you see it generates right SQL in LinqPad](https://selvin.pl/linqpad1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly then you would like to use the [IN clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-comparing-or-and-in) rather than the `OR` operator

```sql
SELECT [t0].[Column]
FROM [dbo].[viewTable] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[CompanyCode] IN ('ALPHA','BETA')
ORDER BY [t0].[EditDate] DESC
```

This can be achieved with the following Linq2Entities query:
(I assumed that you are using [ASPxGridView](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridBase.GetSelectedFieldValues(System.String--)).)

```cs
private IQueryable<viewTable> BaseQuery(Models.TestDataContext db)
{
    var companyCodes = gridCompany.GridView.GetSelectedFieldValues("CompanyCode")
        .Select(row => row.ToString())
        .ToList();

    return db.viewTables.Where(t => companyCodes.Contains(t.Comp_Code));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Peter, it worked like a charm!
Yes your assume that i using ASPxGridView is perfect..

Answer (score 1):

Using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) you can create extension methods for generically testing collections as filters for LINQ to databases:

```
public static class LinqKitExt { // using LINQKit
#region Predicates
    // searchTerms - IEnumerable<TSearch> where one must match for a row
    // testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
    // r => searchTerms.All(s => testFne(r,s))
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AnyIs<T, TSearch>(this IEnumerable<TSearch> searchTerms, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
        foreach (var s in searchTerms)
            pred = pred.Or(r => testFne.Invoke(r, s));

        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)pred.Expand();
    }
#endregion

#region Filters
#region row matches any of searchTerms
    // searchTerms - IEnumerable<TSearch> where one must match for a row
    // testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
    // dbq.Where(r => searchTerms.Any(s => testFne(r,s)))
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T,TSearch>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, IEnumerable<TSearch> searchTerms, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne) =>
        dbq.Where(searchTerms.AnyIs(testFne));
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T,TSearch>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne, IEnumerable<TSearch> searchTerms) =>
        dbq.Where(searchTerms.AnyIs(testFne));
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T,TSearch>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne, params TSearch[] searchTerms) =>
        dbq.Where(searchTerms.AnyIs(testFne));
#endregion
#endregion
}
```

Of course, there are natural corresponding methods for `AllAre` / `SplitContains` / `WhereAll` / `WhereSplitContains`, etc.

With these extensions available, your query becomes:

```
IQueryable<viewTable> query = db.viewTables.WhereAny(gridCompany.GridView.GetSelectedFieldValues("CompanyCode"), (v,s) => v == s);
```

Note: For situations where `Contains` works, that is probably a better choice.